# NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have followed the tutorial for Reactive Forms (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and tried to adapt for my purposes.

The compiler complains about NG8002 (as shown in title), and despite importing `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule`, it still compains about it.

ng version output:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.7
Node: 12.22.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.7 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.7 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.7 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.7 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.7 (cli-only)
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "DTSFrontEnd2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/DTSFrontEnd2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DTSFrontEnd2:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "DTSFrontEnd2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "DTSFrontEnd2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "DTSFrontEnd2:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "DTSFrontEnd2:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "DTSFrontEnd2"
}
```

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ImporterContainerComponent } from './importer-container/importer-container.component';
import { ImportNavComponent } from './import-nav/import-nav.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ImporterContainerComponent,
    ImportNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ImporterContainerComponent,
    ImportNavComponent
  ]
})
export class ImporterModule { }
```

Component

```
<h2>Import Diagrams</h2>

<p>Upload unit and crew diagrams here. Ensure that they are both for the same date / days run</p>

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name for diagram set</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unit diagrams</td>
      <td><input type="file" [formControl]="units" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Crew diagrams</td>
      <td><input type="file" [formControl]="crews"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<button>Upload</button>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-importer-container',
  templateUrl: './importer-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./importer-container.component.css']
})
export class ImporterContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  crewFile!: File;
  unitFile!: File;
  crews: FormControl;
  units: FormControl;

  constructor() {
    this.crews = new FormControl('');
    this.units = new FormControl('');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

The compiler complains that `NG8002: Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

Having looked at similar questions on here, they all point to `ReactiveFormsModule` being a required import - as you can I have that here.

Some suggest having `BrowserModule` and `FormsModule` as well --  I have tried various combinations, tried adding these modules to the exports and still come up blank.

It is likely something obvious, but can not see the wood for the trees right now!

Comment: this is your code on stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugnghc?file=src/app/app.component.ts) nothing is wrong with it ;-)

Comment: @swshaun `ImporterModule` in this module, remove `BrowserModule`, and use only `CommonModule` in import array  of `ImporterModule`

Comment: Ok, this is weird! Maybe there is something wrong on my local machine!

Comment: I cannot figure it out, so have reverted to using ```(change)="onChange($event)"``` instead, and done it in a slightly more imperative way.